# List<List<Box>> is not Serialized

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a class `Player` that has three variables, one of these is a `List<List<Box>>` and of course class `Box` does implement `Serializable`.
`Box` has some variables too, all of them are primitive types except for a class `Dice` which does implement `Serializable` too.

I have to send this class through the network with a socket and when I send this to the Client side the `List<List<Box>>` looks ok, and each `Box` too, the problem is that the `Dice` class that should be in the `Box` is always set to null even if the one I sent to the Client from the Server is not and I am absolutely sure that the network part is correct.

Forgot to mention that `List<List<Box>>` when instantiated becomes an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Box>>` which should be Serializable.

`Dice` class:

```
package ingsw.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice implements Serializable {
    private int faceUpValue;
    private final Color diceColor;

    public Dice(Color diceColor) {
        this.diceColor = diceColor;
    }

    public Dice(int faceUpValue, Color diceColor) {
        this.faceUpValue = faceUpValue;
        this.diceColor = diceColor;
    }

    /**
     * Draft the dice
     * get a random number between 1 and 6 and set the faceUpValue
     */
    void roll() {
        int value = (new Random()).nextInt(6) + 1;
        setFaceUpValue(value);
    }

    public int getFaceUpValue() {
        return faceUpValue;
    }

    public void setFaceUpValue(int faceUpValue) {
        this.faceUpValue = faceUpValue;
    }

    public Color getDiceColor() {
        return diceColor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (faceUpValue != 0) {
            return diceColor.toString() + String.valueOf(faceUpValue);
        } else {
            return diceColor.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

`Card` class implements Serializable:

```
    public abstract class PatternCard extends Card {
        private int difficulty;
        protected List<List<Box>> grid;

        public PatternCard(String name, int difficulty) {
            super(name);
            fillGrid();
            this.difficulty = difficulty;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "PatternCard{" +
                    "'" + getName() + "'" +
                    '}';
        }

        public int getDifficulty() {
            return difficulty;
        }

        public void setGrid(List<List<Box>> grid) {
            this.grid = grid;
        }

        public List<List<Box>> getGrid() {
            return grid;
        }

        private void fillGrid() {
            this.grid = new ArrayList<>(4);
            this.grid.add(new ArrayList<>(5));
            this.grid.add(new ArrayList<>(5));
            this.grid.add(new ArrayList<>(5));
            this.grid.add(new ArrayList<>(5));
            }
}
```

`Box` class:

```
public class Box implements Serializable {
    private Color color;
    private Integer value;
    private Dice dice;

    public Box(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Box(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean isValueSet() {
        return value != null;
    }

    public void insertDice(Dice dice) {
        this.dice = dice;
        //TODO the dice at this point must removed from the dice drafted --> dices (set).remove();
    }

    public void removeDice() {
        if (dice != null) dice = null;
        //TODO dice must be re-added?
    }

    public Dice getDice() {
        return dice;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (isValueSet()) return String.valueOf(value);
        else return color.toString();
    }

    Boolean isDiceSet(){ return dice != null; }
}
```

I've investigated a bit and thought that I should probably Serialize the object and De-serialize it by myself but I don't know if that could be the real issue here since ArrayLists are Serializable and every object inluded in these ArrayLists are too.

What could possibly be wrong in this?

Comment: We won’t be of much help without seeing the code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've updated the OP with some code, I've explained in detailed what was Serializable and what was not, I don't know how much of a help will that be.

Comment: Is `Color` from the `java.awt` package?

Comment: Nope, it's an enum I've created @Logan and it does implement Serializable, they should be Serializable by default but when I ran out of ideas I've set it pretty much everywhere just to be sure that I didn't miss anything

Comment: Still not a MCVE. If you're sure about the network part, you should be able to reproduce the problem with a simple program.

Comment: The solution to this was to reset() the outputstream